# Hot to set Require SSL on IIS application by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

Trying something like this:

```
$site = Get-IISSite |? Name -Match <...>
$app = $site.Applications |? Path -Match <...>
$app.SetAttributeValue('sslFlags', 'Ssl')
```

The fact is `sslFlags` still doesn't exists and apparently `SetAttributeValue` cannot add a new attribute because I get an error.

```
Exception while calling "SetAttributeValue" with "2" arguments: "Index not valid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070585)"   (translated)
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: At client or server?  See following for client.   You should use both TLS 1.2 and 1.3 so add two together : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-the-tls-version-in-powershell : [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 + [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using app.exe instead.
For example, I have a webapi(name:testapp) under "Default Web Site", Now I want to set the key "sslFlags" to "Ssl" in the powershell:

sslFlags is under section:system.webserver/security/access
[Check the Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access)

1:Unlock the section

& "$env:SystemRoot\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" unlock config /section:system.webServer/security/access

2:Modify

& "$env:SystemRoot\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config "Default Web Site/testapp" /section:system.webServer/security/access /sslFlags:"Ssl"
[image: See Microsoft Doc]

Then the web.config changed.

[image]

By the way: I test the following command
[image]
No error appears but couldn't see any change in the webconfig.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I found the Powershell way to this by the new `IISAdministration` module should be something like:

```
$site = Get-IISSite |? Name -Match <...>
$service = $site.Applications |? Path -Match <...>
Get-IISConfigSection -Location $service -SectionPath "system.webServer/security/access" | Set-IISConfigAttributeValue -AttributeName sslFlags -AttributeValue Ssl
```

Can someone confirm?